# Communication.ContactName Entity not recognized in LUIS Intent

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have created several utterances in LUIS for an intent to create new meeting items in my application.

[image]

I have tagged the corresponding elements in the utterance to recognize the name of the invited person and the date / time of the meeting.
When I train the model and test it afterwards, date and time is recognized every time. Not so for the contactname. I have tried all possible things like adding the utterance as pattern, adding phrase lists, but no success.

What can I do, to make this work? Is there anythink I am missing?

Comment: I have played around with Prebuilt Domains and added the Calendar Domain in LUIS. Apart from restricted entities available (Subject and Location) these don't work either. I don't get Subject or Location information even when using the prebuilt domain. The entity type working 100% reliable is DateTimeV2

Comment: What kind of entity are you using for Communication.ContactName? 
If Simple or Pattern: How many utterances have you created for this intent? If you have less than 10-15, it could be the model isn't trained enough to recognize the name. 

Do you have different names for all utterances? Using the same name repeatedly may cause faulty training.

Have you tried a Composite Entity? For example, creating a MeetingEntity that includes ContactName and datetimeV2 as children of that MeetingEntity, then training that might help.

Comment: After using different names in utterances, appearing in my phrase lists for name, the trained model works pretty nice. I am using a simple entity type for the entity. Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using simple entities, keep in mind that you'll need to train 10-15 utterances, and that there should be different names in all utterances. Using the same name repeatedly may cause faulty training.